# how to get JRadioButton text value

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

```
male_btn = new JRadioButton("Male");
        fmale_btn = new JRadioButton("Female");
        btn_group = new ButtonGroup();
        btn_group.add(male_btn);
        btn_group.add(fmale_btn);
```

how to get JRadioButton value using button group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
btn_group.getElements().nextElement().getText()
```

i.e iterate over enumeration of elements btn_group.getElements() for traversing to jradiobutton.

Answer (score 1):

```
Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = btn_group.getElements();
for(Abstract button: buttons){
if (button.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println(button.getText());
        }
}
```